# Comparing corresponding elements of two lists in Django Template

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, list, django-templates

I have two lists of equal sizes like so:

```
change_list = ['none', 'M', 'D', 'none]

print_list = ['examples', 'app.py', 'list.fr', 'template']
```

I pass them through the view and I need to know what the value is on the first list so I can display the elements of the second one with a different color according to what's on the first list.
For example, I need to display 'app.py' as orange in the template due to the 'M' in the first list.

I've searched around and I have no idea how to do this. I tried to pass the len of the list as a range to the view like this:

```
{% for i in len%}
    {% if changes_list.i == "M" %}
        <p style="color:orange;"> {{print_list.i}}</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But it didn't work.

I'm not sure if I formulated the question correctly but I wasn't exactly sure how to explain this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What you want is format items from print_list depending on the corresponding items (same index) in change_list ? If yes, check my answer below.

Comment: Your answer is spot on! Thank you!

Comment: For clarity sake you should change you title to something along the line of "Comparing corresponding elements of two list in Django Template". Not perfect but would help future search on the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give a shot like below. Warning, untested code ;)

In your view :

```
change_list = ['none', 'M', 'D', 'none']
print_list = ['examples', 'app.py', 'list.fr', 'template']
template_list = list(zip(change_list, print_list))
```

And you just pass template_list to your template.

In your template :

```
{% for i in template_list%}
    {% if i.0 == "M" %}
        <p style="color:orange;"> {{i.1}}</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

And you should be good.

Please note that in the view I use list() aroud zip() because I do not know if a zip object would work in a Django template. Feel free to test without it.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for! The zip object also works with the Django Template.

Comment: Glad it helped. Thank you for the return on the zip object.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is off

Here's a simple solution:

We loop through the list and check if the i is equal to "M"

```
{% for i in change_list %}
    {% if i == "M" %}
       <p>I</p>
    {% else %}
        <p>I Not == M</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you wanted to compare the two lists:

```
{% for i in change_list %}
    {% for x in print_list %}
      {% if i == x %}
       <p>I</p>
      {% else %}
        <p>I Not == X</p>
      {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This may be because of how I worded the title but this is not what I was looking for. The accepted answer solves my problem. Thank you for your contribution anyway!